# Handling huge list of arguments in python

Tags: python

I have list of ids (each time varies) & its huge lists (max 30,000 ids). I wanted to give this list as a argument & proceed further action. I am thinking of collect all ids list (every time) in a flat file or json format & pass this in my python code? Is is a correct approach or is there any other way?

Comment: Can you give a code example to clarify your explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to write this to a file. You can simply pass the list directly to your function. The list will be passed by reference and so there is no duplication of data nor additional RAM usage. Here is an example:

```
In []: def fun(a):
   ...:     print(len(a))
   ...:     a.append("added in function")
   ...:

In []: import random

In []: lst = [random.random() for i in range(30000)]

In []: lst[0]
Out[]: 0.8447635417487326

In []: lst[-1]
Out[]: 0.8361118812403031

In []: len(lst)
Out[]: 30000

In []: fun(lst)
30000

In []: len(lst)
Out[]: 30001

In []: lst[-1]
Out[]: 'added in function'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments !! Let me try